# Most efficient way to find friends of friends, excluding friends

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table called friends, and for each friendship, I add two entries. For example, if users 1 and 2 are friends, we will have:

```
uid1 uid2
----------
1    2
2    1
```

My goal is to find friends of friends, exclding the friends. The following query gives me friends of friends (including friends):

```
SELECT f2.uid2 FROM friends f1, friends f2 WHERE f1.uid1='YOUR_ID' AND f1.uid2=f2.uid1 AND f2.uid2!='YOUR_ID'
```

My preference is not to use IN or NOT IN. Can you think of anything to supplement this query?

Comment: Why did you add both records for a friendship? Won't that duplicate the records?

Comment: It makes things easier. I won't need CASE statements this way.

Comment: A RDBS is not proper for a graph. For this special requirement it's OK, but you might consider switching to a graph DBS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an outer join with your own friends so you can filter them out.

```
SELECT f2.uid2 FROM friends f1
JOIN friends f2 ON f1.uid2 = f2.uid1
LEFT JOIN friends f3 ON f3.uid2 = f2.uid2 AND f3.uid1 = 'YourID'
WHERE f1.uid1='YourID' 
AND f2.uid2!='YourID'
AND f3.uid2 IS NULL
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90899/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an additional `join` and aggregation:

```
SELECT f2.uid2
FROM friends f1 join
     friends f2
     on f1.uid1 = 'YOUR_ID' AND f1.uid2 = f2.uid1 AND f2.uid2 <> 'YOUR_ID'` join
     friends f3
     on f2.uid2 = f3.fuid1
GROUP BY f2.uid2
HAVING sum(f3.uid2 = 'YOUR_ID') = 0;
```

Comment: You can't have `your_id` condition in join clause if you are using a prepared-statement (which you shall).